# Difference between どこが and どこで in sentence

Tags: particle-が, particle-で

I was practicing some writing and attempted to write the following sentence

> Where can I find the cat food?

I originally wrote

> 僕は**どこが**猫用の食べ物を見つけられますか。

However I was corrected to

> 僕は**どこで**猫用の食べ物を見つけられますか。

What is the difference between the two sentences? Why is どこが wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どこが is wrong (here) as the place is not the subject of that sentence. Imagine to replace it with the position of the cat food: (wrong) 僕はトイレが猫用の食べ物を見つけられます. Here you probably wouldn't even consider saying it in this way.

So the right thing to do is to use で for the place you do the action (searching), therefore also for the question word that asks for this place.

Answer (score 2):

The answer might be grammatical but it sounds slightly off, you want to say

Neko no esa wa doko ni arimasu ka.

The whole "where can I find" idiom doesn't make sense in Japanese.